# Trying to use IF/CASE Statement within a Where Clause using BETWEEN in Oracle

Tags: oracle, case

I am trying to do the following CASE statement within a WHERE clause and it's not working. I have searched everywhere and can't find a solution. The error report says:

```
PL/SQL: ORA-00905: missing keyword.
```

Which keyword is missing?

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
    INTO v_sql_count
    FROM xaction_level_info b
    WHERE v_measure_map(i).v_upload_code = b.UPLOAD_CODE
    AND v_xs_scope(j).v_scope_key        = b.SCOPE
    AND 

    CASE WHEN
    v_measure_map(i).v_date_stamp='Benchmark_Date' THEN 
    v_xs_scope(j).v_enriched_date BETWEEN NVL(b.effective_start_time, 00000000000000) AND NVL(b.effective_end_time, 99999999999999)
    ELSE
    v_xs_scope(j).v_enriched_time BETWEEN NVL(b.effective_start_time, 00000000000000) AND NVL(b.effective_end_time, 99999999999999) 
    END
    AND b.level_order =
      (SELECT MIN(level_order)
      FROM xaction_level_info
      WHERE SCOPE                                   = b.SCOPE
      AND UPLOAD_CODE                               = b.UPLOAD_CODE
      AND NVL(effective_start_time, 00000000000000) = NVL(b.effective_start_time, 00000000000000)
      AND NVL(effective_end_time, 99999999999999)   = NVL(b.effective_end_time, 99999999999999)
      ) ;
```

I tried this method but it's not giving me the results I desire. Can someone explain why? Oracle seems only be using v_xs_scope(j).v_enriched_time regardless of whether Enriched_Date is in the date_stamp field or not.

```
    CASE WHEN
    v_measure_map(i).v_date_stamp='Enriched_Date' THEN 
    v_xs_scope(j).v_enriched_date
    when 
    v_measure_map(i).v_date_stamp='Benchmark_Date' THEN 
    v_xs_scope(j).v_benchmark_date
    ELSE
    v_xs_scope(j).v_enriched_time 
    END
    BETWEEN NVL(b.effective_start_time, 00000000000000) AND NVL(b.effective_end_time, 99999999999999)
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using the `CASE` expression, you could just use an `OR` expression to take both options into account.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) -- Match for measure value on these keys.
        INTO v_sql_count
        FROM xaction_level_info b
        WHERE v_measure_map(i).v_upload_code = b.UPLOAD_CODE
        AND v_xs_scope(j).v_scope_key        = b.SCOPE
        AND (
                (
                v_measure_map(i).v_date_stamp='Benchmark_Date'
                AND v_xs_scope(j).v_enriched_date BETWEEN NVL(b.effective_start_time, 00000000000000) AND NVL(b.effective_end_time, 99999999999999)
                )
            OR
                (
                v_measure_map(i).v_date_stamp<>'Benchmark_Date'
                AND v_xs_scope(j).v_enriched_time BETWEEN NVL(b.effective_start_time, 00000000000000) AND NVL(b.effective_end_time, 99999999999999) 
                )
            )
        AND b.level_order =
          (SELECT MIN(level_order)
          FROM xaction_level_info
          WHERE SCOPE                                   = b.SCOPE
          AND UPLOAD_CODE                               = b.UPLOAD_CODE
          AND NVL(effective_start_time, 00000000000000) = NVL(b.effective_start_time, 00000000000000)
          AND NVL(effective_end_time, 99999999999999)   = NVL(b.effective_end_time, 99999999999999)
          ) ;
```

Comment: Almost...the idea's right but you probably need to protect the second term in the OR with `(v_measure_map(i).v_date_stamp != 'Benchmark_Date' OR v_measure_map(i).v_date_stamp IS NULL) AND` so that the main OR term only fires when the first term is false.  And you mostly fixed that while I was typing...we need to know whether the `v_date_stamp` value can ever be NULL to know whether that's safe.

Comment: Great. Can you make sure that you mark this as the correct answer? Thanks

Comment: Actually Declan_K - after testing your answer, I realized its actually not working the way I need it. Instead of picking up v.enriched_date when date_stamp = Benchmark Date and using the value in v.enriched_date to compare between effective start time and effective end time - it is instead only using v_enriched_time.